# Xamarin.iOS app launch crash, no crash logs and no failure message in console

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash, xamarin.ios

I am trying to run my application in the latest version of Xamarin studio 5.10.2 with iOS 9.2 simulator and device, but each and every time when I try to run my app my app will just display splash screen and immediately it crashes. No crash logs is getting generated nor a failure message in console.

I tried clean build, cleaning Xamarin studio cache data, resetting simulator, cloned a fresh copy of my project but unfortunately none of these things are helping me out :(.

P.S: The same app and the same git branch is working like a charm for my team members inn their machines, I just wonder with this strange behaviour of Xamarin studio! ;  Other projects are running successfully in my machine except one of the main project.

Any help in resolving this issue is much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to catch any unhandled exceptions by adding this to the Application **static void Main**

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (o, e) => 
{ 
    #if DEBUG
        Debugger.Break ();
    #endif
};

TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (o, e) => 
{
    #if DEBUG
        Debugger.Break();
    #endif
};
```

> EDIT Also a good suggestion would be to install a crash analytics tool
>   (like [Hockeyapp](https://www.hockeyapp.net/)) to catch any other crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I once faced same problems as yours. I would like to share. What I do is:

1. Search and delete the unused NuGet Packages, components and references in my coding.
2. Clean up solution, quit Xamarin Studio.
3. Delete folders /bin and /obj in Project folder in both Android and iOS project.
4. Open up the project, Rebuild All.

Then, the app works well.